# Extracting certain landcover type in CONUS with Google Earth Engine?

Tags: python, google-earth-engine, land-cover

I am new to Google Earth Engine and I would like to export the pixels with landcover type of deciduous broadleaf forest (MCD12Q1 with LC_Type1 equals to 4) in google earth engine. And the following is my code:

```
import ee
import ee.mapclient
import datetime

# generate region of interest
ee.Initialize() 
#Define a region roughly covering the continental US.
roi = ee.Geometry.Rectangle(-127.18, 19.39, -62.75, 51.29)  


# Load country boundaries from a Fusion Table.
countries = ee.FeatureCollection('ft:1tdSwUL7MVpOauSgRzqVTOwdfy17KDbw-1d9omPw');

# Get a feature collection with just the US feature.
US = countries.filter(ee.Filter.eq('Country', 'United States'));

# create clipping function
def clip_roi(image):
    return image.clip(roi)
def clip_US(image):
    return image.clip(roi).clip(US)

# create a QA mask function
def dbfmasker(image):
    mask1=image.select('LC_Type1').eq(4)
    mask2=image.select('QC').eq(0)
    mask3=image.select('LW').eq(1)
    return image.updateMask(mask1).updateMask(mask2).updateMask(mask3)

# compilie the data
dataset =(  ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MCD12Q1')\
         .filterDate('2010-01-01', '2015-12-31')\
         .select(['LC_Type1:Land_Cover_Type1','QC','LW']) \
         .map(dbfmasker)
         .map(clip_US)          )

count = dataset.size()
print count
```

I got stuck here because the count value I printed here was not a number. However, I tended to use it as the iteration range later when exporting the data pixel by pixel.